# How do i make my side drawer expand when API data loads?

Tags: css, reactjs, api

I'm working on a bookshelf project. I'm still new to programming, but i managed to make the Google Books API work so far, but when I receive the search results, my side drawer (side menu) doesn't expand.

Also, if I want to make a "load more results", what would be the best approach?

Video of the problem: https://www.loom.com/share/12ab331cf37f41038f6da294f5e5ea29

Vercel: https://academicshelf.vercel.app/discover

Best regards,
Frederik

Comment: Please add code examples to the question of what you tried and did not succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So rather than "expanding" the side bar, make it's `height: 100vh` and `position: fixed`. That way, as the user scrolls, the side bar scrolls with them.

As for the "load more results" bit, this is dependent upon your implementation. You're either going to want to paginate or do "infinite scrolling". Pagination can take on the look of a bar at the bottom with total results and different pages, or a simplified version of it would literally just add an element to the bottom that says "load more..." and will load the next set of elements by expanding upon the current list. This prevents the client from downloading a lot of content for items they will never see. For performance, I would recommend lazily loading the next set of results so that when the user clicks the button, it loads the next set instantaneously.

Comment: Thanks mate! I'll give it a go tomorrow and let you know if it worked out.

Comment: Thanks again mate! I just implemented the side bar code and it worked well.

I regards to the "load more results" i will have to do some reading. I have never tried it before, so i don't know which implementation will work the best for my project, but thank you so much for the help!